# Stars of macros in definition of another starred/unstarred macro look like disconnected in some circumstances

Tags: glossaries, starred-version

This question follows a previous question of mine: [Prepend different stuffs to starred and unstarred \chapter commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162339/prepend-different-stuffs-to-starred-and-unstarred-chapter-commands).

In some circumstances, a starred macro in definition of another starred/unstarred macro doesn't work as expected. The following MCE works like a charm but, as soon as the `glossaries` packages is loaded, the star of `\resetsecnumdepth` looks like disconnected: it appears in the text.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tocvsec2}
% \usepackage{glossaries}
%
\let\ORIchapter\chapter%
\RenewDocumentCommand\chapter{som}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {
     \setsecnumdepth{none}%
    }
    {%
     \resetsecnumdepth*
    }
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
    {\ORIchapter{#3}}
    {\ORIchapter[#2]{#3}}%
}
%
\setsecnumdepth{chapter}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\end{document}
```

The problem doesn't come from `xparse` package, as the following MCE, using only
LaTeX macros, has the same trouble.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocvsec2}
\usepackage{glossaries}
%
\let\ORIchapter\chapter%
\makeatletter%
\renewcommand\chapter{%
  \@ifstar{\starred@chapter}{\unstarred@chapter}%
}
\newcommand{\starred@chapter}{%
  \setsecnumdepth{none}%
  \ORIchapter%
}%
\newcommand{\unstarred@chapter}{%
  \resetsecnumdepth*
  \ORIchapter%
}%
%
\makeatother%
%
\setsecnumdepth{chapter}
\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}
\end{document}
```

I had a look of the `glossaries`' code, and made some tests (patching the
`glossaries` macros involving `\chapter` in order they use `\ORIchapter` instead) but I didn't succeed to debug the trouble (neither warning nor error in the `.log` file).

Comment: `glossaries` doesn't explicitly redefine `\@ifstar` so it must load something else that does.

Comment: It's `amsgen` that redefines it.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot I identified wrongly the source of the problem; the bug is indeed in `tocvsec2`. Sorry.

Comment: @egreg Drat those pesky spurious spaces `:-)`

Comment: Note that `tocvsec2` (2014/03/10 v1.3a) should have solved the issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's another case of a spurious space!

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tocvsec2}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\resetsecnumdepth{%
  \@ifstar{%
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{\value{max@secnumdepth}}%
    \edef\stack@secnumdepth{\the\c@secnumdepth\relax}%
  }{%
    \ifx\stack@secnumdepth\@empty
      \PackageWarning{tocvsec2}{There is no previous value for secnumdepth}%
    \else
      \afterassignment\gobble@secnumdepth
      \expandafter\c@secnumdepth\expandafter\numexpr\stack@secnumdepth\@nil
    \fi
  }%<--- Was missing
}
\makeatother

\let\ORIchapter\chapter
\RenewDocumentCommand\chapter{som}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {
     \setsecnumdepth{none}%
    }
    {%
     \resetsecnumdepth*
    }
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
    {\ORIchapter{#3}}
    {\ORIchapter[#2]{#3}}%
}

\setsecnumdepth{chapter}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\end{document}
```

What happens? In `amsgen.sty`, `\@ifstar` receives a new definition based on `\new@ifnextchar`, which does not ignore spaces like it happens for `\@ifnextchar`.

The missing `%` in the definition causes `\new@ifnextchar` not seeing the `*` as the next character, but a space.

The problem shows because `glossaries` loads `amsgen` via `amsmath`.

Comment: OK.I'll let know Will Robertson, the current `tocvsec2` maintainer.

Comment: Who would guess: you found a missing `%` :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: not me, for sure! :)