# \chaptertitle from titleps ignored after redefinition of \chapter macro

Tags: sectioning, chapters, titlesec, starred-version, titleps

The following MWE shows that, if the `\chapter` macro is redefined as in a previous question of mine: [Prepend different stuffs to starred and unstarred \chapter commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162339/prepend-different-stuffs-to-starred-and-unstarred-chapter-commands), the `\chaptertitle` macro from the `titleps` (or in `titlesec`?) package is ignored with e.g. `\tableofcontents`, `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables` commands (but is not ignored with ordinary chapters).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xparse,xpatch}
\usepackage{titleps}
\usepackage{tocvsec2}
%
\makeatletter%
% Hack to be sure \resetsecnumdepth* from tocvsec2 behaves well
\@ifpackagelater{tocvsec2}{2014/03/10}{%
}{%
  \renewcommand\resetsecnumdepth{%
    \@ifstar{%
      \setcounter{secnumdepth}{\value{max@secnumdepth}}%
      \edef\stack@secnumdepth{\the\c@secnumdepth\relax}%
    }{%
      \ifx\stack@secnumdepth\@empty%
      \PackageWarning{tocvsec2}{There is no previous value for secnumdepth}%
      \else%
      \afterassignment\gobble@secnumdepth%
      \expandafter\c@secnumdepth\expandafter\numexpr\stack@secnumdepth\@nil%
      \fi%
    }%
  }%
}%
\makeatother%
\let\ORIchapter\chapter%
\RenewDocumentCommand\chapter{som}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {
     \setsecnumdepth{none}%
    }
    {%
     \resetsecnumdepth*
    }
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
    {\ORIchapter{#3}}
    {\ORIchapter[#2]{#3}}%
}
% we don't want \chapter* for \tableofcontents and similar lists
\xpatchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\chapter}{\ORIchapter}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\listoffigures}{\chapter}{\ORIchapter}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\listoftables}{\chapter}{\ORIchapter}{}{}
% populate the stack
\AtBeginDocument{\setsecnumdepth{none}}
%
\newpagestyle{liminary}[]{%
  \sethead[\thepage]%
  []%
  [\chaptertitle]%
  {%
    \sectiontitle%
  }%
  {}%
  {\thepage}%
  \headrule%
}%
%
\pagestyle{liminary}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\chapter{A 1st chapter}
\lipsum[1-10]
\section{A 1st section of the 1st chapter}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

If the lines:

```
\xpatchcmd{\listoffigures}{\chapter}{\ORIchapter}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\listoftables}{\chapter}{\ORIchapter}{}{}
```

are commented, the corresponding `\chaptertitle` are not ignored (maybe with side effects I didn't notice) but if the line:

```
\xpatchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\chapter}{\ORIchapter}{}{}
```

is commented, a "TeX capacity exceeded" error arises:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\@nameuse #1->\csname #1
                        \endcsname 
l.62 \tableofcontents

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Maybe it could be helpful to notice that, with or without:

```
\xpatchcmd{\printglossary}{\chapter}{\ORIchapter}{}{}
```

the `\printglossary` command behaves well w.r.t. `\chaptertitle`, as shown by the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xparse,xpatch}
\usepackage{titleps}
\usepackage{tocvsec2}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{bar}{%
  name={bar},
  description={bar}
}
%
\makeatletter%
% Hack to be sure \resetsecnumdepth* from tocvsec2 behaves well
\@ifpackagelater{tocvsec2}{2014/03/10}{%
}{%
  \renewcommand\resetsecnumdepth{%
    \@ifstar{%
      \setcounter{secnumdepth}{\value{max@secnumdepth}}%
      \edef\stack@secnumdepth{\the\c@secnumdepth\relax}%
    }{%
      \ifx\stack@secnumdepth\@empty%
      \PackageWarning{tocvsec2}{There is no previous value for secnumdepth}%
      \else%
      \afterassignment\gobble@secnumdepth%
      \expandafter\c@secnumdepth\expandafter\numexpr\stack@secnumdepth\@nil%
      \fi%
    }%
  }%
}%
\makeatother%
\let\ORIchapter\chapter%
\RenewDocumentCommand\chapter{som}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {
     \setsecnumdepth{none}%
    }
    {%
     \resetsecnumdepth*
    }
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
    {\ORIchapter{#3}}
    {\ORIchapter[#2]{#3}}%
}
% we don't want \chapter* for \tableofcontents and similar lists
\xpatchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\chapter}{\ORIchapter}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\listoffigures}{\chapter}{\ORIchapter}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\listoftables}{\chapter}{\ORIchapter}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\printglossary}{\chapter}{\ORIchapter}{}{}
% populate the stack
\AtBeginDocument{\setsecnumdepth{none}}
%
\newpagestyle{liminary}[]{%
  \sethead[\thepage]%
  []%
  [\chaptertitle]%
  {%
    \sectiontitle%
  }%
  {}%
  {\thepage}%
  \headrule%
}%
%
\pagestyle{liminary}
\glsaddall
\begin{document}
\printglossary
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\chapter{A 1st chapter}
\lipsum[1-10]
\section{A 1st section of the 1st chapter}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Hence my question: is it possible to adjust the redefinition of the `\chapter` macro as in a previous question of mine: [Prepend different stuffs to starred and unstarred \chapter commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162339/prepend-different-stuffs-to-starred-and-unstarred-chapter-commands) in order `\chaptertitle` from `titleps` package is not ignored for commands like `\tableofcontents`, `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables`?

Comment: I don't precisely know what's going on, but adding `\gdef\chaptertitle{\contentsname}` before `\ORIchapter` in the patch to `\tableofcontents` seems to work. The problem seems to be in the fact that there are concurrent tries to redefine `\chapter`

Comment: OK. Is it safe to drop the lines that patch `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables` (to make them use `\ORIchapter` instead of the new `\chapter` macro)?

Comment: @egreg In fact, it is not enough in the case the `glossaries` is used (as in the second MWE above): in such a case, the `\chaptertitle` of `\tableofcontents` is the `glossaries`' one: "Glossary".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `titlesec` package redefines `\chapter` at begin document, so you have to delay your own redefinition.

I present the version with the glossary, to show that everything goes well; I removed the hack for `tocvsec2` since I updated my distributions.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xparse,xpatch}
\usepackage{tocvsec2}
\usepackage{titleps}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\AtBeginDocument{% delay the redefinition when titlesec has done its own
\let\ORIDENISchapter\chapter
\RenewDocumentCommand\chapter{som}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {
     \setsecnumdepth{none}%
    }
    {%
     \resetsecnumdepth*
    }%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
    {\ORIDENISchapter{#3}}
    {\ORIDENISchapter[#2]{#3}}%
}
}% end of \AtBeginDocument
% we don't want \chapter* for \tableofcontents and similar lists
\xpatchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\chapter}{\ORIDENISchapter}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\listoffigures}{\chapter}{\ORIDENISchapter}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\listoftables}{\chapter}{\ORIDENISchapter}{}{}
% populate the stack
\AtBeginDocument{\setsecnumdepth{none}}
%
\newpagestyle{liminary}[]{%
  \sethead[\thepage]%
  []%
  [\chaptertitle]%
  {%
    \sectiontitle%
  }%
  {}%
  {\thepage}%
  \headrule%
}%
%
\pagestyle{liminary}

\newglossaryentry{bar}{
  name={bar},
  description={bar}
}

\glsaddall


\begin{document}
\printglossary
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\chapter{A 1st chapter}
\lipsum[1-10]
\section{A 1st section of the 1st chapter}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

The top of page 4 (the empty page after the table of contents) shows the correct title.

[image]